# Making a Chat Applications

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongoose, axios, chat

I am trying to make a chat application with help of Axios but I am facing some problem in the backend codes.
**When I post a new message to an already created chatroom it does not get added to the messages array. Can someone help me with this, or tell me a better way to make a chat application.??**

HERE IS MY CHATROOM ROUTER

```
.post(isUser,(req,res,next)=>{
    Chat.findOne({chatroomId:req.userId+' '+req.params.matchId})
    .then((chat) =>{
        console.log(chat);
        if(chat === null){
            var classId = req.userId+' '+req.params.matchId;
            var message = req.body.message;
            var sender  = req.userId;
            Chat.create({
                chatroomId:classId,
                messages:{
                    message:message,
                    sender:sender
                }})
            .then((chat) =>{
                res.statusCode = 200;
                res.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
                res.json(chat);
            }, err => next(err) )
        }
        else{
            chat.messages.push({
                message:message,
                sender:sender
            });
            chat.save();
            res.statusCode = 200;
            res.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
            res.json(chat);
        }
    },err => next(err))
    .catch(err=> next(err))
})
```

Comment: This question is practically unanswerable, as it currently is. 1) we can't run this code because it's dependant on a lot of your local setup that no one has access to. See http://sscce.org/ 2) You haven't really described what exactly the issue is, and because we can't run the code (as mentioned in #1), we can't find out for ourselves, either.

Answer (score 1):

`save()` function is asynchronous.So you need to handle it asynchronously.
Try out this:

`Previous code`

```js
chat.save();
res.statusCode = 200;
res.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
res.json(chat);
```

`Improved code`

```js
chat.save((err,ch)=>{
       res.statusCode = 200;
       res.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
       res.json(ch);
 });
```

Comment: no does not work

Comment: @AbhishekShah Neither `sender` nor `message` values are defined in else block.They are defined in `if` block. Move the definition of these variables one block higher and try again